# How to populate specific DataTable column with values

Tags: c#

Hello I have a dataTable updatedValues, and I was wondering if there was a way to set a value of the column with a value.

```
int rowindex = 0;
foreach(string val in something)
    {
    try
        {
        updatedValues.Columns["Books"][rowindex] = val;

        Console.WriteLine("Went Here");
        }
    catch
       {
       }

    rowindex++;
    }
```

The try obviously won't compile because it has incorrect syntax, but I was wondering if there was anything similar to what is in the try.

Comment: Probably is _updatedValues.Rows[rowindex]["Books"] = val;_ but then you will have other problems. Are the number of Rows enough to store your val? If not you need to add new rows to your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing but I will take a stab at a response.

DataTables are matrices, similar to Excel, so to reference a specific value you would access it with something  like this code:

```
var myVal = dataTable.Rows[row][column];  //To get a value
```

or

```
var x = 1;
var y = 3;  
dataTable.Rows[x][y] = myVal;  //To set a value
```

And as Umphishrey's McGee posted just before me you can iterate over the values.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are trying to set the column value for all the records in your datatable. If so, you can loop through all records in your datatable and set it.

```
foreach ( DataRow dr in updatedValues.Rows )
{
    dr [ "Books" ] = val;
}
```